# Transmit.app won't upload any files; asks me to make sure I have permission to edit the file

Tags: ftp

Whenever I try to upload a file using [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/). It always displays an error "Transmit can't  upload the file. Make sure you have permission to edit this file."

I have contacted both Panic, who seem to think it is something to do with my server's configuration, and my server provider, who seem to think it is something wrong in Transmit.

Does anyone know what the error means and what I can do to correct it?

Comment: A good way to troubleshoot this would be to login to the server (using `ssh`) and list the directory permission using `ls -ld <uploaddirname>`. Ideally, it should be writable by the user id you're using to connect to the server using Transmit. You can further verify this by creating a file with `touch <dirname>/<filename>`. If it succeeds, then the server and user permissions are fine.

Comment: One more thing to try is to use a different FTP program, like the free [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) app to see if you face the same issue. That will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Unfortunately SSH is not an option, and I have tried several other FTP clients and they all work but Transmit is better for my needs. It also seems to be specifically SFTP Transmit has a issue with, FTP works fine. But Good security practice means I need SFTP.

Comment: For me it was just one file that had this behavior. The filename was super long, so I reduced the length of the filename to half and then it uploaded fine.